# Why is fastcgi sending an array into trim() in option.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running a wordpress server, and it crashes after about five hours of operation. Resetting it allows the server to work for a while, but it eventually crashes again.

I think that the below error from the error log is the cause. The crash follows two of these logs.

```
2015/12/16 15:18:35 [error] 7541#0: *2065 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 30
PHP message: PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 30" while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.33.64.70, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php"
```

Is FastCGI sending in an array to option.php or is this likely a theme issue with wordpress? Please, any help would be appreciated, this server issue is getting bad.

Comment: Have you examined the files in the error message?

Comment: Yeah, option.php comes with the wordpress install so I assume it isn't the problem, but probably something that calls on the get_option() function that's passing in the wrong things

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with FastCGI. It is simply reporting what it has received over the STDERR channel from the WordPress application.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm experiencing a similar issue.